# Proving the existence of unique polynomials in polynomial division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm trying to follow along someone's proof, but I don't understand how they get to the line at the bottom.

Theorem:

Let $f(x), d(x) \in R[x] $ and $d(x) \ne 0.$ Then there exist unique polynomials d(x) and r(x) such that

$f(x) = q(x)d(x) +r(x), deg(r(x)) < deg (d(x))$.

The proof starts by proving the uniqueness of the polynomials d(x) and r(x) like this:
For uniqueness, suppose

$f(x) = q_1(x)d(x) + r_1(x), deg(r_1(x)< deg(d(x))$

$f(x) = q_2(x)d(x) + r_2(x), deg(r_2(x))<deg(d(x))$.

Then I don't understand how they go to the next line:

$r_1(x)-r_2(x)=d(x)(q_2(x)-q_1(x))$

The proof continues, but I won't bother you.

Comment: Subtract the two equations and bring the two $r_i$ to one side and keep the rest of the stuff in the other.

Comment: @conditionalMethod My subtracting top from bottom yields me $r_1(x)-r_2(x) = q_1(x)d(x) - q_2(x)d(x) = d(x)(q_1(x)-q_2(x))$ which isn't totally right... did I subtract wrongly?

Comment: When you subtract all the terms are on one side. When you take the $dq_i$ to the other side the $dq_1$ is the one that gets the $-$ and $dq_2$ the $+$.

Comment: Brilliant, I understood, by putting both equations on each side of the =, I was able to advance!